# Raster layer, updated via dataProvider writeBlock, image oscillates between old and new data

Tags: qgis, raster, pyqgis

I have updated a raster layer using dataProvider writeBlock. However when moving the location around and zooming in and out the image oscillates between old and new data.

I have changed the data of a QgsRasterLayer changed using:

```
rasterlayerprovider.setEditable(True)
rasterlayerprovider.writeBlock(block, 1,0,0)
rasterlayerprovider.setEditable(False)
rasterlayerprovider.reload()
```

In this case a curved shape is stamped on the raster.

Zooming in or out or moving the window causes the image to oscillate (inconsistently) between the new and the old raster data.

Various means of trying to solve the problem:

```
rasterlayer.dataProvider().reloadData()
rasterlayer.triggerRepaint()
iface.mapCanvas().refresh()
iface.layerTreeView().refreshLayerSymbology(rasterlayer.id())
QgsProject.instance().reloadAllLayers()
```

The following screencast shows movement by grabbing the canvas and when there is no grab mouse icon the scale is being changed zooming in and out.

[View screencast here](https://user-images.githubusercontent.com/122863290/212844698-f28cc3bb-d216-4819-a0f2-6f9498c03636.mp4)

If the screen cast does not work then the attached gif images show the same [image: View gif here]

Comment: This is on QGIS version 3.28.0-Firenze